# Is it possible to change an instantiated object's parameters after it has been constructed?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, parameters, worldwind

For example, I have a constructor that makes Markers, and an array list that stores the Markers. The constructor needs Position, attributes, and a heading. I'm looking to move this marker around, so I want to find a way to change the marker's Position parameter after it has been constructed.

```
Marker marker=new BasicMarker(vehiclepos, attrs, vehicleheading); 
vehiclelist.add(marker);
```

Is there a way to do this? 
Or, if there is a better way of moving these markers, what would that way be?

Comment: Does the property in question have a setter? We can't see your code.

Comment: Excuse me sir, if you don't mind, please post your `BasicMarker` class..

Comment: @Yuliam Chandra The BasicMarker class is a pre-built class, the documentation can be found here: [link](http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.4/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/render/markers/BasicMarker.html)

Comment: Give each marker a unique name/id, and use a hashmap to store each marker and reference them by that to change position. `vehicleHashMap.get(markerId).setPosition(postion)`

Comment: After you moving the marker, do you still want to add it to your list?

Comment: I have a list for the vehicle marker and a list for the respective markers' positions (for another purpose in the program). I'd like to keep the vehicle on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the parameters from the constructor and make them accessible.

```
public class Marker {

int x;

public Marker(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Marker m = new Marker(3);
    System.out.println("before: "+m.x);
    m.x = 2;
    System.out.println("after: "+m.x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, your class needs a method called a setter.  Something like this:

```
public void SetPos(String NewPos) {
    this.vehiclepos = NewPos;
;
```

More information can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html

Comment: thanks. Right now, I have one big method called setVehicle() that deals with all the position and marker creating. So I should break the big setVehicle method into a smaller setVehiclePosition() method?

Comment: Yes, that would make it easier to reset each parameter and also clean up your code some.